# How to remove zombie process from my own C UNIX shell

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, posix, waitpid

I am writing my own UNIX-shell in C, If write `&` at the end of the command then the parent wont stop for the child to end and child will be backgrounded.

To remove the zombie child process I am using `waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG)` but it `returns 0` and does not remove any zombie process, while there are zombie process.

What changes should I make?

```
//Everything is inside a while loop
     pid_t pid, wpid;
    
     pid=fork();
     
    if(pid==0){
    
        char *args1[] = {d1,NULL};   //d1 is the input from the user        
        
        execvp(d1,args1);
         
         exit(pid);
     }
        
     if (background == 0){ //If parent has to wait for the child to end
         waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
     }
     else{      //If parent does not wait for the child to end
                          
         fprintf(stderr, "Starting background process...\n");
          waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG);

    }
```

[image: My shell output]

Here "shell" is the name of my C program.

As you can see an `ls<defunct>` process is still there even after using `waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG)`

Comment: The waitpid(,,WNOHANG) is guaranteed to not block. But you still have to wait for the child process.

Comment: But the parent cant wait for the child process to end.

Comment: You could catch SIGCHLD and wait after the signal has been raised. Or just wait periodically, e.g. before issuing a new pronpt (for an interactive shell)

Comment: But why waitpid(,,WNOHANG) is not working?

Comment: You want to test the value returned by `waitpid()` and act accordingly.

Comment: That was shorthand, I omitted the first two arguments -->> `waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG)`. You do know what *blocking* means in this context?

Comment: You claim `waitpid` is returning 0, but your code discards the value returned by `waitpid`, so how do you know?  Is this the actual code?  It looks like a simple race condition; the parent is calling `waitpid` before the `ls` has finished.  After the `waitpid` returns, `ls` finishes and the process is a zombie until the next call to `waitpid`.

Comment: thank you this is what was happening